# React increment and decrement numbers in console.log

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Maybe I'm not quite comprehending React.. So I'm trying to increment and decrement numbers but when I console.log, I see one number less or more in the console. I'm assuming this is because number starts with 0. Is there way I could match what I'm pressing and what's on the console?

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Numbers() {
  const [number, setNumbers] = useState(0);

  const onClickIncrease = () => {
    console.log(number);
    // I have tried the following:
    // setNumbers(number + 1);
    setNumbers((prev) => prev + 1);
  };

  const onClickDecrease = () => {
    console.log(number);
    setNumbers((prev) => prev - 1);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={onClickDecrease}>-</div>
      <div>{number}</div>
      <div onClick={onClickIncrease}>+</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It has to do with react state being async, can check the link above.

---- IGNORE BELOW ----

```
const onClickIncrease = () => {
   console.log(number); // output will be 0
   setNumbers((prev) => prev + 1);
   console.log(number); // output will be 1
};
```

And yes, the number starts with 0 because the argument passed in useState is 0.

```
const [number, setNumbers] = useState(0);
```

Comment: I don't think this is it, I think it's the fact react state is async

Comment: `console.log(number); // output will be 1` is incorrect, `number` will still be `0` because React state updates are asynchronously processed. It pretty much has everything to do with React.

Comment: oh noted, sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useState } from "react";
 export default function Numbers() {
 const [number, setNumbers] = useState(0);  
  console.log(number);
return (
<>
  <div onClick={()=> setNumbers(number - 1)}>-</div>
  <div>{number}</div>
  <div onClick={()=> setNumbers(number + 1)}>+</div>
</>
```

);
}

Comment: We have matching number with the console.log. However, what's the actual mechanism behind this? What's the actual difference between using prev => prev +1 or setNumbers(number + 1) in a function than actually applying on the click?

Comment: write another function for match value.

Comment: inside useeffect